# Sql query between two dates without year for zodiac?

Tags: mysql

I have columns Name and BirthDate with data eg: 1999-10-06.

I need query for Libra: September 23 - October 22, how to do this? I dont need the year.

Expecting something like this but not working:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM persons WHERE BirthDate BETWEEN '%9-23' AND '%10-22' ";
```

Comment: What is type of `BirthDate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

% is only a wildcard when used with LIKE, which isn't helpful here.  You can do something like

```
where case month(BirthDate) when 9 then day(BirthDate) >= 23 when 10 then day(BirthDate) <= 22 end;
```

Comment: thx its working. but somehow when i run it in phpmyadmin it has "unrecognized keywords" and "unexpected token."

Comment: sounds like a problem with phpmyadmin.  does it understand mysql syntax and functions?

Comment: im new with phpmyadmin dont know how to explain, you know like those syntax warnings, somehow its working with my php script that all that matters.

Answer (score 0):

You should use build-in function dayofyear

```
SELECT * 
FROM dates 
WHERE DAYOFYEAR(birthDate) 
   between DAYOFYEAR(CONCAT(year(birthDate),"-09-23")) 
      AND DAYOFYEAR(CONCAT(year(birthDate),"-10-22"))
```

#### Live:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1625c/8

Comment: but the dayofyear range will be different depending on if BirthDate is or is not in a leap year

Comment: Edited to dynamic dayofyear